# Unable to filter using a DateTimeFilter, all results returned instead

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to implement a basic "starts before"/"starts after" filter for one of my models. Unfortunately, the filter never gets applied. What am I doing wrong?

**Model**

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    ...snip...
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    ...snip...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('station', 'employee', 'confirmed', 'start_time',)
```

**FilterSet**

```
import django_filters
from serverapp.models import Shift


class ShiftFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    """
    A filter to enable fetching shifts within a date range
    """
    # Specify the URL parameters we can use for filtering
    start_before = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(
        name="start_time",
        lookup_type="lte")
    start_after = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(
        name="start_time",
        lookup_type="gte")

    class Meta:
        # Specify the mode we're filtering on
        model = Shift
        # Specify the fields you can filter by (in this case just the
        # two above)
        fields = ['start_before', 'start_after']
```

**View**

```
class ShiftViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ShiftSerializer
    filter_class = ShiftFilter
    ...snip...
```

**Query (using HTTPIE)**

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/shifts/?start_before=2015-04-23
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/shifts/?start_after=2015-04-23
```

**Records**

```
id  start_time              end_time 
13  2015-04-16 16:18:13     2015-04-17 16:18:13
14  2015-04-16 16:18:13     2015-04-17 16:18:13
15  2015-04-24 16:18:13     2015-04-24 17:18:13
```

I would expect `start_before=2015-04-23` to return the two records dated 04/16/2015, and `start_after=2015-04-23` to return the one record dated 04/24/2015. Unfortunately, regardless of which of the two queries I run, I get back all three records.

This seemed so simple a thing to implement, how could I have screwed it up?

Comment: did you add `filters.DjangoFilterBackend` to your `filter_backends` ?

Comment: @soooooot You got it! If you submit it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna use `django_filters`, please add `filters.DjangoFilterBackend` to your `filter_backends`.

for GLOBAL :

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    #...
    # !!! it's a list or tuple !!!
    # of course, you can add other backends
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": ( 
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    )
    #...
}
```

for specific view:

```
class ShiftViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ShiftSerializer
    filter_class = ShiftFilter
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

Comment: Thank you for going above and beyond and posting some practical examples, I was worried you'd end up posting a one-liner answer and I'd have to awkwardly edit in something for future viewers.